# Sanitizing Web Queries

Tags: c#

My WPF C# client app makes web queries to application server.  I want to sanitize any values, not for SQL injection the application server already takes care of this, but for invalid characters in the web query.  For example:

```
string data = "o'reilly";
string url = $"https://myserver/api/myapi?$filter=value eq @p1 &@p1='{data}'";
using var stream = await myHttpClient.GetStreamAsync(url);
```

Sure for a single quote this can solve the problem:

```
string data = "o'reilly";
data = data.Replace("'", "''");
string ulr = $"https://myserver/api/myapi?$filter=value eq @p1 &@p1='{data}'";
using var stream = await myHttpClient.GetStreamAsync(url);
```

Doing that means that I have to manual sanitize for every possible invalid query.  That is too easy to miss something or do it wrong.  Adding in the fact that we need the application to be multi-language.

PS: sorry if this has been answered all my searches return SQL injections for the server-side and as I said the application server already takes care of that.

Comment: You want to URL encode, not HTML encode. You will want to encode each component, individually (not the entire string).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I follow your question, you want to html encode your query string. There's a framework method that does that: [`HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmlencode).

Build the url then encode it all or call it on each  parameter.